# Проблема с копированием в буфер обмена js

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, clipboard

Нужна помощь с расширением в chrome. Я хочу выделить текст - нажать на кнопку расширения в контекстном меню - обработать текст - записать обработанный текст в буфер обмена.
При записи в буфер выдает ошибку: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Document is not focused.

Как мне обойти ошибку?
Спасибо.

Код:

```
function toNormalCase (invalidText) {
    return invalidText.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + invalidText.toLowerCase().slice(1);   
}

function wordSplitter (wholeName) {
  return wholeName.split(' ');
}

function toLowerCaser (fullName) {

  const splittedName = wordSplitter(fullName.selectionText);
  let normalName = '';

  for (let word of splittedName) {
  normalName = normalName.concat(toNormalCase(word) + ' '); 
  }
  console.log(navigator.clipboard.writeText);
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(normalName.slice(0, -1));
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Make It Normal Case", 
  contexts:["selection"], 
  onclick: toLowerCaser
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "ToLowerCaser",
    "description": "Just a thing, that makes names into normal cases",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "icons": {"128": "icon_128.png"},
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "background": {
         "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>",
        "storage",
        "contextMenus",
        "clipboard"
        ]

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56306153/domexception-on-calling-navigator-clipboard-readtext

Comment: @Denis640Kb Этот способ не помогает